# Why is `delegatecall` not working with simple example on quorum node?

Tags: quorum, delegatecall

Deploying these two contracts:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

// NOTE: Deploy this contract first
contract B {
    // NOTE: storage layout must be the same as contract A
    uint public num;
    address public sender;
    uint public value;

    function setVars(uint _num) public payable {
        num = _num;
        sender = msg.sender;
        value = msg.value;
    }
}

contract A {
    uint public num;
    address public sender;
    uint public value;

    function setVars(address _contract, uint _num) public payable {
        // A's storage is set, B is not modified.
        (bool success, bytes memory data) = _contract.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSignature("setVars(uint256)", _num)
        );
 
    }
}
```

If I execute it in remix VM Shanghai it works well.
But if I execute it in my local **quorum** node, it doesn't work.

My genesis file:

```js
{
  "alloc": {
    "0xed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d": {
      "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "0xca843569e3427144cead5e4d5999a3d0ccf92b8e": {
      "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "0x0fbdc686b912d7722dc86510934589e0aaf3b55a": {
      "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "0x9186eb3d20cbd1f5f992a950d808c4495153abd5": {
      "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
    },
    "0x0638e1574728b6d862dd5d3a3e0942c3be47d996": {
      "balance": "1000000000000000000000000000"
    }
  },
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "config": {
    "homesteadBlock": 0,
    "byzantiumBlock": 0,
    "constantinopleBlock": 0,
    "petersburgBlock": 0,
    "istanbulBlock": 0,
    "chainId": 10,
    "eip150Block": 0,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip150Hash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "eip158Block": 0,
    "qip714Block": 20,
    "isQuorum": true,
    "privacyPrecompileBlock": 0,
    "maxCodeSizeConfig" : [
      {
        "block" : 0,
        "size" : 64
      }
    ]
  },
  "difficulty": "0x0",
  "extraData": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0xE0000000",
  "mixhash": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000647572616c65787365646c6578",
  "nonce": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp": "0x00"
}
```